# Adding a custom http header to a spring boot WS call (wstemplate)

Tags: java, spring, soap

I followed this guide "Consuming a SOAP web service", at
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ 
and changed it to call my own internal SOAP service, it makes the call
as expected, however now I need to pass an http header via the WsTemplate,
what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

public class WsHttpHeaderCallback implements WebServiceMessageCallback
{

```
public WsHttpHeaderCallback()
{
    super();
}

@Override
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException
{
    String headerKey="headerkey";
    String headerValue="headervalue";
    addRequestHeader(headerKey, headerValue);     
}

private void addRequestHeader(String headerKey, String headerValue) throws IOException
{

    TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
    WebServiceConnection connection = context.getConnection();

    if (connection instanceof HttpUrlConnection) {
        HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpUrlConnection) connection;

        conn.addRequestHeader(headerKey, headerValue); 

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem. If it can help someone, I've found a solution here: [Spring WS Add Soap Header in Client](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-add-soap-header-client/)

The idea is to create a class implementing `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceMessageCallback` and override the `doWithMessage()` method.
The `doItMessage()` method takes a `WebServiceMessage` as argument and is invoked by the `springWs` process before sending the request, allowing to modify it before it is send.

What is done in the example above is marshalling the object and adding it to the header of the request.

In my case I have to be careful with XML annotations of the object to be set as header, especially the @XmlRootElement with the namespace attribute.

Once this is done, the `WSClient` has to be adjusted to use the `marshalSendAndReceive()` method that takes a request and an uri, a payload object, and a `WebServiceMessageCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but found some [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html)

For setting WS-Addressing headers on the client, you can use the org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.client.ActionCallback. ...

```
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(o, new ActionCallback("http://samples/RequestOrder"));
```